# Erro biblioteca OSMAR (OpenStreetMap)

Tags: r

Olá,
Estou tentando usar a biblioteca OSMAR no R para plotar rotas e não estou conseguindo.

```
library(osmar)
library(leaflet)
library(igraph)

src <- osmsource_api()

get_osm(node(18961430), source = src)
```

Está aparecendo o seguinte erro:

```
Space required after the Public Identifier
SystemLiteral " or ' expected
SYSTEM or PUBLIC, the URI is missing
Opening and ending tag mismatch: hr line 7 and body
Opening and ending tag mismatch: body line 4 and html
Premature end of data in tag html line 2
Error: 1: Space required after the Public Identifier
2: SystemLiteral " or ' expected
3: SYSTEM or PUBLIC, the URI is missing
4: Opening and ending tag mismatch: hr line 7 and body
5: Opening and ending tag mismatch: body line 4 and html
6: Premature end of data in tag html line 2
```

Alguém teria uma dica sobre o que esta acontecendo? Pois meu código esta minusculo e o erro foi logo no inicio.

desde já, obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este erro é um problema de acesso ao servidor do open street map, onde os dados estão armazenados. Basicamente, o pacote está desatualizado e tenta acessar usando o protocolo http, mas atualmente apenas acessos via https são permitidos. Uma maneira de resolver este problema é declarando explicitamente a url da api utilizando https:

```
library(osmar)
library(leaflet)
library(igraph)

src <- osmsource_api(url = "https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/")

get_osm(node(18961430), source = src)
osmar object
1 nodes, 0 ways, 0 relations
```